# Reading empty file in C++ returns 255, 0 expected

Tags: c++, readfile, eof

When I run my code to read file it works in every way. Any ASCII code I find in file, can get printed using my function. But when it reaches EOF I would expect it to return 0, but it returns 255 instead. Why does that happen and how do I fix that.
Segment of my code:

```cpp
uint8_t FileDevice::read () {
    ifile.open(this->fileName);
    if (!ifile) ifile.open(this->fileName.c_str(), ifstream::app);
    ifile.seekg(this->position);
    uint8_t character;
    character = ifile.get();
    ifile.close();
    this->position++;
    printf("%d\n", character);
    return character;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect `get`to return 0? It returns a wider integer type in order to be able to return an "invalid" value.

Comment: @molbdnilo And for context let it be said that this idea is originally from the C standard library. It's pretty elegant: How else would one communicate EOF? Throwing an exception would be bad design because EOF is not really unexpected, all to the contrary (one *could* throw for genuine I/O errors though). The only alternative would be to hand in a reference or pointer and return a diagnostic value, à la scanf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possibility of returning EOF is the main reason [`istream::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) does not return a `char` but a wider integer type.

If EOF would be returned as `0` you would not be able to distingish it from a non-EOF `0`.

The value of `EOF` is part of the char traits of the stream. You can find it here [`std::char_traits<CharT>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/eof).

As its all templates and no specific `CharT` refered to in documentation it can be cumbersome to wade through. This site as a very handy overview also listing most important features of the `char_traits<char>`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits.

Last but not least, EOF is specified to be negative and once wrapped around you cannot tell the difference between a "good" value and the EOF. Hence you should not use `uint8_t` for the return value of `get`. Use the appropriate integer type and only after checking for EOF you can store it the target type.

Comment: I get what you are saying now and understand it, thanks. I ment to ask why doesn't it return acutual value "0x00" which is the code for the last byte in text file. I than figured out that the file I did tests on was corupted. Ty

Comment: @GabrijelOkorn you say the file you read is empty. Or is it not empty?

Comment: Command hexdump <file> says it has nothing in it.

Comment: This is file example I expected to read "00" from:     
```hexdump FA.dev 
0000000 2031 2032 0a33 0a39 0a32               
000000a
```

Comment: I am not familiar without output of hexdump. But anyhow, your question is asking about reaching eof and thats what I answered. I am not sure if I understand what you say, but If you acutally wanted to ask a different quesiton  you can open a new question.

Comment: We learned in school that there is a "0x00" character describing the end of file. I expected it but didn't get it in my example. I figured out the problem was my "weird" file. I works now and I understand it, thank you.

Comment: @GabrijelOkorn A null byte does not indicate end of file, neither in DOS/WIndows (there it is 26, corresponding to Ctrl-Z) nor in Unix (there it is 4, Ctrl-D). A null byte *does* indicate end of string, in memory. A typical text file will not contain either of those three characters (the end-of-file condition is communicated to the program from the file system). The I/O routines then have their own way to communicate that to the user -- e.g. formatted input will set a flag in the stream object, and converting it to bool suddenly yields false.

Comment: *We learned in school that there is a "0x00" character describing the end of file.*  That is not the case for any platform I have ever used.  And I have used many different platforms.